# XML content does not seem to be XML: 'eae-5f67afd5c3dc'

Tags: r, web-scraping

Just like in the case of many R newbie like me, I am trying to read an html page but I am faced with above error.

```
##scraping 
library(XML)
my_url <- "https://www.amazon.com/b?node=16225009011&pf_rd_r=8XMGCHCR9WSKKEK3024T&pf_rd_p=5232c45b-5929-4ff0-8eae-5f67afd5c3dc"
html_page <- htmlTreeParse(my_url,useInternalNodes=TRUE)
```

I have tried out different solution on StackOverflow but am not getting it right. Also I used the help function to check the documentation of **htmlTreeParse** and I don't seems to understand what **useInternalNodes** means and it functionality

Comment: Maybe try a more modern package like `httr`: `httr::GET("https://www.amazon.com/b?node=16225009011&pf_rd_r=8XMGCHCR9WSKKEK3024T&pf_rd_p=5232c45b-5929-4ff0-8eae-5f67afd5c3dc")`

Comment: What is your objective?

Comment: @xwhitelight I am following a tutorial on how to web scrape product page. so I want to scrape things like product title and price

Comment: @okoliechukwuka Use `rvest` for scraping HTML static page. https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-web-scraping-rvest

Comment: @MrFlick The response from the get request is just 10 lines of html tags. I need to get the full html page which comprise of about 1000 html tags

Comment: @xwhitelight I will check that out. is there any other good library you can recommend as well for web scraping. for instance I want to scrape pages with **infinite scroll** or maybe I want to pass through links like a `crawler` in python

Comment: @okoliechukwuka In R you use `rvest` for static HTML pages and `RSelenium` with Docker for dynamic data (infinite scroll is one of those)

Comment: But with dynamic pages, usually, I would go to the Network tab of Dev tool and check where the data comes from first and try to scrape from that. In most cases, I don't need to use `RSelenium`.